# How to manage Node.js application on Linux (Fedora-15)

Tags: linux, node.js, fedora

I have started to learn [`Node.js`](http://nodejs.org/) i have installed `node.js`, [`mongodb`](http://www.mongodb.org/) and the `mongojs` as described in the [**Blog Post**](http://howtonode.org/node-js-and-mongodb-getting-started-with-mongojs). I am using Fedora 15, i'm new to this linux environment, can anybody guide me how to manage the application on my machine, i have a background of working with the microsoft web stack and i am used to the IDE, i'm finding it difficult to usderstand the directory structure of linux, where i'm going to put my files how i'm going to structure an application when using node.js...

---

*i hope i have asked the question in right place or should i have asked it on Programmer.stackexchange? Plz don' say that i shouldn't have asked it in first place...*

Comment: You shouldn't have asked it in first place. ;-) More seriously, if you don't understand Linux environment then forget about Node.js and learn Linux! Or switch to Windows, Node.js also works on Windows, you know?

Comment: yes i know it works on windows but that requires a lot of doing nipping and tucking... also i wanted to use it in its native environment, how hard it could be to understand the basic structure of linux ... is it really difficult??

Comment: P.S tnx for not DV(ing) my question `:)`, i'm not "that" new to linux i have using it in my virtual box for around a year now but never really used it for development

Comment: Basics of Linux are not difficult at all. But unfortunetly stackoverflow's not the place for learing Linux. Try this: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxdir.html this: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/shell.html and this: http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxfiles.html . I am in a good mood so I won't downvote your question, but be prepared that it might get downvoted.

Comment: By the way: some say that the best IDE for linux is VIM. I do not agree with this (VIM is quite difficult to learn and customize) and I used it for almost a year. I use customized gedit now.

Comment: ok thanks alot @freakish for providing the links i am going to read them now... also i think i should delete the question , will do in couple of mins... tnx again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, since your question actually received an upvote I will answer it. :-)

As I wrote in comments these links are good to start:

[tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxdir.html](http://tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxdir.html)

[tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/shell.html](http://tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/shell.html)

[tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxfiles.html](http://tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/linuxfiles.html)

Or just google for "Linux tutorial", "Linux basics", etc. and read **EVERYTHING** you'll see.

Now when you will get a bit more familiar with the files structure you should do the following: go to `/home/username` and create a directory there for your app. Then you just add files in there.

There are several reasons for doing this but the most important is permissions. You don't want to give to much permissions to your app because of the risk of hacker's attack.

Good luck and have fun with Linux and Node.js.